# Ubuntu on Mac: does it belong on Ask Different or on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, ask-different, askubuntu

Which StackExchange site if preferred when asking questions specific to Apple hardware, but concerning running Ubuntu?

Specific example, would be "*how to get hardware component X of MacBook Pro running in Ubuntu XX.YY?"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is about Apple hardware, I would ask the question on *Ask Different*.
If the question is about the Ubuntu driver to use for specific hardware, then I would ask the question on *Ask Ubuntu*, or *Super User* if the correct answer could be given from who has experience with both Mac OS software and Ubuntu software.

Answer (score 5):

It would really depend on your question—if it's more about Ubuntu, and you're just incidentally running it on Apple hardware, I would go with Ask Ubuntu. On the other hand, if it's more a hardware problem, Ask Different might be the better place, but I would also seriously consider Super User. Without more information, I'm afraid it's really hard to say exactly which site would consider it on topic.

Comment: OP probably specifically doesn't want SU. http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2464/trigger-happy-moderators-deleting-answers-for-no-reason

Comment: @random: actually I wouldn't consider SU, because I don't see how Windows users are going to be useful in answering Ubuntu/Mac related questions.

Comment: @vartec Super User isn't just for Windows—it's for all computer hardware and software questions.

Comment: @vartec Super User is not only for Windows users. A question about software that is not a developer tool is on-topic on Super User. As there is also _Ask Different_, I would probably ask on SU a question that is about an integration issue between Windows and Mac OS X.